# How I can select 2 variables from the list of data within mapply or Map functions in R?

Tags: list, for-loop, apply, map-function, spatstat

I have a list of data frames from which 2 variables: utmX and utmY will be used for this analyze.

In the code below, I am trying to:
1) write L.fun()
2) apply this L.fun() to a list of data frames
3) plot result of each data frame separately.

```
L.fun <- function(x, y){
  window <- ripras(x, y)
  p.patt <- ppp(x, y, window=window)
  L <- Lest(p.patt, correction="Ripley")
  return(L)
}

 data.list <- list(data1,data2,data3...data30)

 L.res <- mapply(L.fun, data.list$utmX, data.list$utmY)  # empty
 L.res <- mapply(L.fun, x$utmX, x$utmY) # x object not found
 L.res <- Map(L.fun, data.list)         # arg y is missing 
 plot(L.res)
```

Also I tried this by including x and y inside of function, stil not working.

```
 L.res <- lapply(data.list, function(x) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
       window <- ripras(x$utmX, x$utmY)
       p.patt <- ppp(x$utmX, x$utmY, window=window)
       x$L <- Lest(p.patt, correction="Ripley")
   }
   x
 })
```

So my question is how I can select 2 variables that going to be used for mappy and Map functions from the list of data?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification of your second attempt should work.

```r
library(spatstat)
```

First generate a list of 2 fake datasets:

```r
data.list <- replicate(2, data.frame(utmX=runif(20), utmY=runif(20)), simplify = FALSE)
```

Run through the list and apply the L function to each dataset in the list:

```r
L.res <- lapply(data.list, function(x) {
  window <- ripras(x$utmX, x$utmY)
  p.patt <- ppp(x$utmX, x$utmY, window=window)
  return(Lest(p.patt, correction="Ripley"))
})
```

The result is a list of two L functions as shown in the plot:

```r
plot.anylist(L.res)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! there is a warning message "data contain duplicated points".

Comment: Is the warning from your actual dataset or the artificially generated one I made above? I presume it is from your own data. It simply means you have at least two observations with exactly the same x,y coordinates. Usually in point pattern analysis it is assumed that you can only have one point in one location.

Comment: yes, It is from my data. so should I delete overlaped ones?

Comment: I believe most analyses in spatstat will just ignore it, so it shouldn't cause too much trouble. However, if it makes sense in your application to say that there can only be one point at a given location you might as well delete duplicates and avoid any problems. You can use the function `duplicated()` to find and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
coor <- lapply(data.list, function(x) cbind(x$utmX, x$utmY))
pats <- lapply(coor, as.ppp, W=ripras)
Lfuns <- anylapply(pats, Lest, correction="Ripley")
plot(Lfuns)
```